# inheriting same named methods from different parent class in python

Tags: python, oop

Suppose i am inheriting methods of class A,B and C.

```
class M(A,B,C):
  ......
```

Now all class have same 6 methods. I know that class M will inherit all from class A because it is first in order but what if i want to access some methods from class A and some from class B and some from class class C all having same name

Comment: You can create a method in `M` which explicitly calls one of the specific classes’ methods. But how exactly you’d combine results from three different functions we don’t know. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is worth reading to understand how Python's super builtin works - https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: @deceze  i was reading some oops concept and thought of this question.Maybe i will use these concept later.

Comment: @snakecharmerb read that.

Comment: @deceze how you do that please give an example as an answer.I just need one example of that.